# Django: Twitter login being redirected to Example Domain

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, twitter

I'm using `django-socialregistration` for enabling users to login using their Twitter account on my application.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'socialregistration',
    'socialregistration.contrib.twitter'
)
...
...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.core.context_processors.debug', 'django.core.context_processors.i18n', 'django.core.context_processors.media', 'django.core.context_processors.static', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 'django.core.context_processors.request',) 

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'socialregistration.contrib.twitter.auth.TwitterAuth',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

SITE_ID = 1

SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'GetEvangelized.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^social/', include('socialregistration.urls',
                namespace = 'socialregistration')))
```

template

```
<body>
        <h1>MicroCelebrity Form</h1><br>
        {% load twitter %}
        {% twitter_button %}    
        <br>
        <form id="evangelized_form" method="post" action="/rango/fillform/">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                <b>{{ field.help_text }}</b><br>
                {{ field }}<br><br>
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

However, on clicking on the Twitter signup button, I get redirected to this:

[image]

The url of this webpage is as follows:

```
http://example.com/social/twitter/callback/?oauth_token=_WtPXwAAAAAAgTIEAAABTim7zYE&oauth_verifier=TheZd4yPsHNCYEi6mPwIvkugirkz20yH
```

The settings of my Twitter application is as follows:

```
Callback URL    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback
Sign in with Twitter    Yes
App-only authentication https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
Request token URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorize URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
Website  http://www.cloudclovis.com
Callback url   http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/twitter/callback
```

What does the 'Example Domain' webpage signify? When I click on the 'More Information' link on that page, I'm redirected to `http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved`

What does that mean? And how can I allow my users to login using their Twitter accounts in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its redirecting there because the default [`sites` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/) has `example.com` as the default site.

You need to change that to `127.0.0.1:8000` if you are in development mode.

To change it, you can use the default admin interface, or simply use the django shell:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

site = Site.objects.get(pk=1)
site.domain = '127.0.0.1:8000'
site.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. However, now if the user is signed in from his/her Twitter account, the application gets redirected to a page which says 'Session expired'. How can I extract a logged-in user's email ID and name from his Twitter credentials? I know this is a whole new question altogether, but I'd really appreciate some help in this matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It says right there in the documentation:

> Also not that Twitter for example will not accept
>   http://localhost:8000 as a valid domain for the callback URL so you’ll
>   have to use http://127.0.0.1:8000 when developing your site.

[Here's the doc page](http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/master/installation.html#note-on-sessions)

EDIT: Okay, I now saw that you have done exactly that.
Can you maybe give more details on the error?